# Magnitude of F given the u component magnitude and 2 angles

Tags: mechanical-engineering

My task is to determine the magnitude of **F**. My guess is that there is some obscure concept that I have yet to learn from class to solve for **F**, but at the time of me posting this, I do not know what this concept is. I tried using the law of sines on the triangle formed by drawing a line between *u* and **F**, but I end up with $\frac{\sin45}{b}=\frac{ \sin C}{8.5}=\frac{ \sin A}{**F**}$. I don't think that I can use the law of cosines for this since it requires two sides and an angle, but feel free to correct me. I'm currently in ME 221 : Engineering Mechanics I if it makes any difference in how people answer this question.
[image]

Comment: Is $v$ relevant to this question in anyway? Is there any _other_ information given along with this question?

Answer (score 1):

$$F_u=F*cos45^{\circ}$$
$$8.5kN= F\frac{ \sqrt{2}}{2}$$
$$F=\frac{8.5kN}{0.7071}=12.020kN$$

Answer (score 0):

> The force $\mathbf{F}$ is to have a component along the $\mathbf{u}$ axis ...

Based on the above,

The component of a vector ($\mathbf{F}$) along another vector ($\mathbf{u}$) is given by the **dot product**.
$$
F_u = \frac{\vec{F}\cdot\vec{u}}{|\vec{u}|} = \frac{|\vec{F}|\ |\vec{u}| \cos{\theta}}{|\vec{u}|}
$$

Comment: Just for clarification, $\theta$ is the angle between **F** and **u**, correct?

Comment: yes. it is the angle between F and u.